# fade in\out works too short and too fast in android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, animation

I'm trying to apply fade-in\out transition in Android.

Can you please tell me why I see the fading only for a moment and then it returns to original alpha?

I have added `setFillAfter(true);` to persist the image disappearance.

I have tried:

```
                animation = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
                        .loadAnimation(AppService.getAppContext(),
                                com.waze.R.anim.fade_out);

                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                boxImage_left.startAnimation(animation);
```

with this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fillAfter="true">
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
         android:toAlpha="1.0"
         android:repeatCount="0"
         android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

and also:

```
                AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
                alpha.setDuration(600);
                animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                animation.setFillAfter(true);
                vImage_left.startAnimation(alpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your activity implements AnimationListener, and set visiblity after animation end.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener
{
    @override
    onCreate(Bundle x)
    {
        ...
        // set animation listener
        animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);
        animFadeOut.setAnimationListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        if (animation == animFadein)
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
         if (animation == animFadeOut)
        {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

And for animation speed modify animation duration and interpolator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **AccelerateInterpolator** you can use **LinearInterpolator**

I know it's too late but will help someone else.